# How to dynamically change the size of a div depending on the amount of content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using absolute positioning for a site. Users have profiles and amount of text they write will vary.

How can I update a `div` elements' height dynamically depending on the amount of text that is being shown, ie. change the `div` height to fit the content dynamically.

```
<div class="profileContainer">
    <h3 class="profileText">
        Here is the text - this could be 1000px height plus
    </h3>
</div>
```

I know the jQuery `height()` method but I'm not sure how to calculate what number to give it - ie. how to find out the height of the text.

Comment: It should work as desired if you won't specify block height (e.g. `auto`): http://jsfiddle.net/8TRh7/.

Comment: I think you dont need to use jquery or js at all. the size of div will change automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page load (or after updating the `h3` element if you have some kind of AJAX request being made) you simply need to set the height of the `#profileContainer` equal to the height of `#profileText`.

Try this:

```
$("#profileContainer").height($("#profileText").height());
```

This is of course assuming that you have set a specific `height` for the container `div` in CSS. If you haven't, then the content of the `h3` will automatically cause the container to grow as required.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to show all the contents then the following css will do the trick.

```
 div.profileContainer {height:auto; width:300px;}
```

That way the container will automatically grow in size to fit the contents and the width will be restricted to 300px

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `css`...

```
<div class="profileContainer" style="height:auto;">
  <h3 class="profileText">
       Here is the text - this could be 1000px height plus
  </h3>
</div>
```